# How to Linq-ify this query?

Tags: c#, linq, select

I currently have this Linq query:

```
   return this.Context.StockTakeFacts
                .OrderByDescending(stf => stf.StockTakeId)
                .Where(stf => stf.FactKindId == ((int)kind))
                .Take(topCount)
                .ToList<IStockTakeFact>();
```

The intent is to return every fact for the topCount of StockTakes but instead I can see that I will only get the topCount number of facts.

How do I Linq-ify this query to achieve my aim?

I could use 2 queries to get the top-topCount StockTakeId and then do a "between" but I wondered what tricks Linq might have.

This is what I'm trying to beat. Note that it's really more about learning that not being able to find a solution. Also concerned about performance not for these queries but in general, I don't want to just to easy stuff and find out it's thrashing behind the scenes. Like what is the penalty of that contains clause in my second query below?

```
List<long> stids = this.Context.StockTakes
                .OrderByDescending(st => st.StockTakeId)
                .Take(topCount)
                .Select(st => st.StockTakeId)
                .ToList<long>();

            return this.Context.StockTakeFacts
                .Where(stf => (stf.FactKindId == ((int)kind)) && (stids.Contains(stf.StockTakeId)))
                .ToList<IStockTakeFact>();
```

Comment: What do you mean Linqify? It is already linq

Comment: @manojlds. I guess _"Linqify"_ is making the linq work, though I didn't check the dictionary... =)

Comment: why dont you SELECT fact, and apply Take(topCount) to StockTake. You will need to join the tables on the Id field.

Comment: To be honest I couldn't think of what to use for the title.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
 return this.Context.StockTakeFacts
                .OrderByDescending(stf => stf.StockTakeId)
                .Where(stf => stf.FactKindId == ((int)kind))
                .Take(topCount)
                .Select(stf=>stf.Fact)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi. no unfortunately again it doesn't grab all stocktakefacts for the top n stocktakes. It grabs the top n stocktakefacts.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're after correctly, how about:

```
return this.Context.StockTakes
    .OrderByDescending(st => st.StockTakeId)
    .Take(topCount)
    .Join(
        this.Context.StockTakeFacts,
        st => st.StockTakeId,
        stf => stf.StockTakeId,
        (st, stf) => stf)
    .OrderByDescending(stf => stf.StockTakeId)
    .ToList<IStockTakeFact>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt using mostly query syntax and using two separate queries:

```
var stids =
     from st in this.Context.StockTakes
     orderby st.StockTakeId descending
     select st.StockTakeId;

var topFacts =
    from stid in stids.Take(topCount)
    join stf in this.Context.StockTakeFacts
    on stid equals stf.StockTakeId
    where stf.FactKindId == (int)kind
    select stf;

 return topFacts.ToList<IStockTakeFact>();
```

As others suggested, what you were looking for is a join. Because the join extension has so many parameters they can be a bit confusing - so I prefer query syntax when doing joins - the compiler gives errors if you get the order wrong, for instance. Join is by far preferable to a filter not only because it spells out how the data is joined together, but also for performance reasons because it uses indexes when used in a database and hashes when used in linq to objects.

You should note that I call `Take` in the second query to limit to the `topCount` stids used in the second query. Instead of having two queries, I could have used an `into` (i.e., query continuation) on the select line of the `stids` query to combine the two queries, but that would have created a mess for limiting it to `topCount` items. Another option would have been to put the `stids` query in parentheses and invoked `Take` on it. Instead, separating it out into two queries seemed the cleanest to me.

I ordinarily avoid specifying generic types whenever I think the compiler can infer the type; however, `IStockTakeFact` is almost certainly an interface and whatever concrete type implements it is likely contained by `this.Context.StockTakeFacts;` which creates the need to specify the generic type on the `ToList` call. Ordinarily I omit the generic type parameter to my `ToList` calls - that seems to be an element of my personal tastes, yours may differ. If `this.Context.StockTakeFacts` is already a `List<IStockTakeFact>` you could safely omit the generic type on the `ToList` call.